# C# VB.NET: How to make a jagged string array a public property

Tags: c#, vb.net, jagged-arrays

all i want to do is this:

```
    Public Property TabsCollection()() as String()()
        Get
            Return _tabsCollection
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value()() as String()())
            _tabsCollection = value
        End Set
    End Property
```

but it errors saying: End of statement expected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<s>TabsCollection()()</s>

<s>value()()</s>

```
Public Property TabsCollection() As String()()
    Get
        Return _tabsCollection
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As String()())
        _tabsCollection = value
    End Set
End Property
```

Answer (score 2):

You have redundant pairs of parentheses:

```
Public Property TabsCollection() as String()()
    Get
        Return _tabsCollection
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value as String()())
        _tabsCollection = value
    End Set
End Property
```

Apart from that, don’t use arrays in that way. Arrays are (almost?) always wrong in a public interface of a class. Furthermore, the name suggests that what you have here is more aptly described by another data structure. A nested array of strings is a circumvention of proper strict typing.

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
Public Property TabsCollection() as String()()
    Get
        Return _tabsCollection
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value as String()())
        _tabsCollection = value
    End Set
End Property
```